# Server Error 500 after passport login

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I use node/express and passport-local for my development. And my session is stored in mongodb. It is strange that after i perform login, I would get server error in following conditions:
1) Using new tab in browser instead of existing tab.
2) After node server restart. 
It doesn't matter which url i am accessing, as long as the host name is of that app, it will always show 500 error page.

I checked that the session (with user credentials) still persist in the mongodb. It can only be resolved when:
1) Clearing the mongodb session database and refresh the page.
2) Clearing the browser cookie and refresh the page.

I am not sure what the problem is. Something very odd to me.
Note that this problem will not exist if user is not login.

Comment: That seems extremely odd to me! Being a passport.js lover I have never seen anything like that. Do you have anymore information on the 500 error?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). This is the only error that appear in my browser console. Do you know how can i debug this??

Comment: I'm assuming this means your're making the request via an ajax call? If so you can look at the response (In Chrome) under the network tab. If not you could also try inspecting it via postman and manually run a post command.

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:3000/server-error
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000. It directly load the server-error page in browser i guess ??? note that his happen after i restart server (if i already login). No matter in which page i am viewing. Not sure where the 500 response came from from the server though.

Comment: @JohnDews it seems that when i access the page localhost:3000/ in postman it returns status code 200 to me...... However, when i access it in browser it return server error message, which will only occur when 500 is respond from server